# Allow a group to run all files under a certain directory in CentOS

Tags: centos, ruby-on-rails, sudo, capistrano

I am trying to set up automatic deployment for my Rails app using Capistrano.  Capistrano will need to run `sudo kill`, and I achieved that without it asking me for a password, by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file (via `visudo`, of course), and added the following line:

```
%deployers  ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/kill
```

However, since I am using RVM single-user setup, the `bundle` executable is at `/home/peddiemarketdeploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/bundle`, so, similarly, I added

```
%deployers  ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/peddiemarketdeploy/.rvm/gems/*
```

in that file as well, and tried to run `sudo bundle`, but sudo still asks me for a password.  Since RVM uses version number in the name of directories, I do not want to hardcode a path into `/etc/sudoers`.  Any ideas how I can edit my sudoers file to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does rvm somehow link to the active ruby instance? That is, is there some sort of symlink called `/home/peddiemarketdeploy/.rvm/gems/$active` that points to whatever the active version happens to be? If so, then allow sudo for `/home/peddiemarketdeploy/.rvm/gems/$active/bin/bundle`. Otherwise write a wrapper script (not in shell, but [perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=perlsec) or [python](https://github.com/ptman/suid-python)) that picks the right version and allow people to run that using sudo.

Comment: No but I guess creating one myself would work for me :)